# What does glyph mean in the Chrome browser?

Tags: google-chrome

In the Chrome browser using the developer tools, on the **Computed** tab there is a section at the bottom named **Rendered Fonts**.  In that section there is an item which lists the font type that is rendered and it states `# glyphs`.  The `#` represents a number from 0 and up.  What does glyph actually mean?  Is it the number of characters?  See screenshot below.  I tried searching the web but didn't find a conclusive answer.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, it appears that this describes the number of characters (glyphs) that were produced from the given font.

- Repeated characters are counted separately ("aabb" = 4 glyphs).
- Blank spaces are included ("a b" = 3 glyphs).
- Ligatures are counted as two separate glyphs ("off" = 3 glyphs even with ff ligature).
- Child elements are not counted (`foo<span>bar</span>` = 3 glyps).

The purpose of the "Rendered Fonts" pane appears to be to show what font substitutions have taken place. For example, even with `font-family: Arial`, Chrome on Windows 7 substitutes SimSun for Chinese characters; inspecting [this JSBin](http://jsbin.com/vanehujodu/1/edit?html,css,output) gives "Arial—8 glyphs, SimSun—2 glyphs".